# What is regular mass spacing?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, spacetime-dimensions, elementary-particles, kaluza-klein

In a book I'm reading, there is a sentence as follows:

> Muons and taus are not extra-dimensional versions of electrons, because they don’t have a regular mass spacing and don’t have the same weak-force interactions as electrons.

What is regular mass spacing?

Please explain to me.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which book?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the book is talking about a [Kaluza-Klein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory) tower of particles, whose masses are regular spaced.